# Kylin Sample Cube on Cloudera doesn't work properly

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cube, kylin

I'm just trying to figure out what's going wrong with my SampleCube, but I don't know how to just find a solution.
First of all, I'm using Cloudera, cdh 5.8.0, Hadoop 2.6.0. I have Hive, HBase and so on.
I had to download binaries for cdh from Kylin's site, and...

Problems which I had and were solved:

1) I had to set a variable KYLIN_HOME, because neither *bin/check-env.sh* nor *bin/kylin.sh start* worked properly. I'd just set it with:

> $ echo "export KYLIN_HOME=/home/cloudera/Kylin_Folder/apache_kylin" >> ~/.bashrc
>   $ source ~/.bashrc

2) I had just problems with mkdir and creating a "/kylin"  folder. I found a solution and tried instruction below. It works.

> sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /kylin

3) And now I try to do sample from Kylin's site

But my cube has no storage at all! That's what I have:

[Overall view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlJuD.png)

When I opened a buld view screen, my build stopped at "#1 Step Name: Create Intermediate Flat Hive Table"
And when I click "Log", I see that:
[Log inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpMiD.png)

Please, help me with that, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, then. I've just found what I had to do.

Steps:

1) Download Kylin for CDH 5.7/5.8 and extract to /opt

2) Export KYLIN_HOME in .bash_profile

3) Restart CDH

4) Run services in cloudera in order: ZooKeeper, HDFS, HBase, Hive, Hue, YARN

5) Add cloudera user to hdfs group: sudo usermod -a -G hdfs cloudera

6) Create kylin folder: sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /kylin

7) Change ownership: sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown cloudera:supergroup /kylin

8) Change permissions: sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod go+w /kylin

9) Load sample: $KYLIN_HOME/bin/sample.sh

10) Start kylin: $KYLIN_HOME/bin/kylin.sh start

11) Navigate to: http://quickstart.cloudera:7070/kylin